# Get row in Grid to evenly divide?

Tags: grid-layouts

I'm having an issue making the second row in this grid space out evenly:

```
Grid[{{Slider[ImageSize -> 300], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, {"l", 
   "c", "r"}}, 
 Alignment -> {{2, 1} -> Left, {2, 2} -> Center, {2, 3} -> Right}, 
 Frame -> All, Spacings -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Updates:**

Response to @MichaelE2: There is still too much space to the right of the slider:

[image]

Response to @m_goldberg: At higher magnifications the slider runs outside the grid:

[image]

Comment: add the option `ColumnsEqual -> True` or the option `ItemSize -> All`?

Comment: It says `ColumnsEqual` isn't an option for `Grid`

Comment: `ColumnsEqual` makes the columns equally spaced, but it also makes the grid a lot bigger for some reason. `ItemSize` does the same thing, too big.

Comment: @user5601 I believe it make all columns equal in width to the item in position `{1, 1}`, the slider.  The `SpanFromLeft` seems to be ignored in considering column widths.

Comment: About your response to me: you didn't use my code. What do you expect me to say? -- If it is somehow connect to my comment, my comment only explained how the widths of the columns are calculated when you use `ItemSize -> All`. The widths is set to the widest column, which is the width of the slider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Pane[
 Grid[{
   {Slider[ImageSize -> 300], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
   {"l", "c", "r"}}, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Baseline,
    {{2, 1} -> Left, {2, 2} -> Center, {2, 3} -> Right}}, 
  Frame -> All, ItemSize -> Scaled[1/3]],
 First@ImageDimensions@
   Rasterize@Grid[{{Slider[ImageSize -> 300]}}, Frame -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to tweak this to get rid of the added space?

Comment: @user5601 What added space?  You specify the slider should have an image size (width) of 300.  There is a small margin around each element plus a frame. IIRC, the overall image size is 313.  Do you want to get rid of the margins? If so, set the width of `Pane` (the second argument) to 300.

Comment: Thanks that does it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
With[{size = 300},
  Grid[
    {{Slider[ImageSize -> size], SpanFromLeft}, {"l", "c", "r"}},
    ItemSize -> {{{1 + size/3/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]}}, 1},
    Alignment -> {{Left, Center, Right}},
    Frame -> All]]
```

[image: grid]

The above code is concise and works for your specific example because, although the alignment specification affects all rows, the slider can't move, so the alignments are only seen in the 2nd row. If in real work, you want only the 2nd row to be affected, then use:

```
With[{size = 300},
  Grid[
    {{Slider[ImageSize -> size], SpanFromLeft}, {"l", "c", "r"}},
    ItemSize -> {{{1 + size/3/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]}}, 1},
    Alignment -> {Center, Automatic, {{2, 1} -> Left, {2, 3} -> Right}},
    Frame -> All]]
```

**Notes**

1. In the specification of the 1st row of the grid only one `SpanFromLeft` need be given.
2. In the 2nd version of code, `{2, 2} -> Center,` is not needed in the 3rd element of the alignment specification because the specification of `Center` in the 1st element sets that as the default.

Comment: See my updates - try changing the notebook magnification.

Comment: @user5601. Yes, it doesn't play well with changes in notebook magnification. Michael E2 approach is better in that it not affected by magnification changes.